# What to use for building a calling app for API below 23?

Tags: android, phone-call, android-phone-call

When going through the [android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/selfManaged) for building a calling app I saw that I need to implement ConnectionService. However I need to Lollipop and ConnectionService has been added in API 23. I couldn't find alternatives in the framework. Am I missing something? How can I achieve this in older platforms?

Comment: Instead of targeting newer versions go for lower versions so it will work.

Comment: @ManojPerumarath That's exactly what I'm trying to do. Lollipop is API 21 and 23 is Marshmallow. I need to support 21 but ConnectionService is available in 23.

Comment: modify your gradle file with buildtoolsversion to a lower level along with targetversion and compileversion to a lower value.

Comment: They are with lower version... @ManojPerumarath do you understand what the problem is? Do I need to edit my question for more clarity?

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is a little late, but it looks like it might not be possible to replace the default dialer before APK-23, as the feature was added in APK-23.

https://medium.com/makingtuenti/android-default-dialer-replacement-part-i-722d05ca50fe